# "I have lost my register"

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

Context: Someone lost his register and now he wants to put a notice on the notice board. Which version of the sentence is correct? If I use "I lost" instead of "I have lost" would it be fine?

> 1. I have lost my register on which my name and address have been written.
> 2. I have lost my register on which my name and address were written.
> 3. I have lost my register on which my name and address are written.

Comment: I wouldn't use any of these. I would simply say. "I have lost my register. My name and address are written on it." There are some instances where two short sentences work much better than just one; this appears to be one of those cases.

Answer (score 1):

2 and 3 are fine although I would lean towards 3.

I would use "have lost" because it carries a sense of recency (same as "I just lost"), and this is difficult to explain, but saying "I lost," to me, at least, has a subtle connotation of being explanatory and ancillary. After hearing "I lost" I would expect a follow up, like a request ("I lost something, so can I borrow yours?").

I would use "have lost" in this announcement.